# Anonymise Zip files in a folder recursively

Tags: linux, osx, zip

I have multiple `zip` files in a parent folder as well as subfolders. I would like to replace all those `zip files` with a dummy zip file. In other words:

```
 * the original zip file content being replaced by the dummy zip file  
 * the original zip file name will remain as it is  
 * the origin zip file path will remain as it is
```

Would you please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: and the original zip files should be overwritten == removed?

Comment: Suppose: I have ./main/subdir/somefile.zip and /path/to/dummy.zip files. I want to replace ./main/subdir/somefile.zip file with /path/to/dummy.zip (preserving name and path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
find /some/path/ -iname "*.zip" -exec cp -f /path/to/dummy.zip {} \;
```

Change `/some/path` to the folder you like to search for the zip-files.

> Warning: this will remove the original contents of all zip-files below `/some/path`.

Comment: That works great!! @Rovo

Comment: How to find types of file in a directory?